# Why using array in command cancels output redirection?

Tags: arrays, bash, io-redirection

I have this (simplified) code:

```
elems="${array[@]}"
do_cmd "xxx" "for_each \"$elems\" func" ">> $log_file" || return $?
```

which redirects output to `$log_file` (as expected).

However, if the code above is simplified as:

```
do_cmd "xxx" "for_each \"${array[@]}\" func" ">> $log_file" || return $?
```

then the output is no longer redirected to `$log_file` (instead it outputs to `stdout`).

Any ideas why?

Note: internally `do_cmd` uses `eval`. The `for_each` is:

```
for_each()
{
  local elems=$1
  local func_and_args=$2

  for elem in $elems
  do
    $func_and_args $elem
  done
}
```

Comment: `set -x` is your friend.

Comment: Also, `elems=${array[@]}` flattens your array into a single string, defeating everything you might have otherwise gained from using an array at all.

Comment: And `$func_and_args` runs you into all the issues described in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050); that's another "don't do that" (whereas `eval` is not just a can of worms but a worm-canning factory; [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) is a place to start).

Comment: ...to be clear, the goal -- using something that looks/smells a lot like function composition for terse flow control -- is _great_, and I wholeheartedly approve; there's just a lot of care that needs to be taken in the tactics to preserve correctness (thus, to avoid writing wildly insecure code).

Comment: BTW, `$?` is the default thing for `return` to use as an exit status, so `|| return` is 100% identical to `|| return "$?"`.

Comment: The _concrete, tactical_ reason `${array[@]}` doesn't work, btw, is that inside double quotes it splits your content into words; so with `array=( "first item" "second item" "third item" )` you get `do_cmd` `xxx` `for_each "first item` `second item` `third item" func` `>> $log_file` as your word splitting

Comment: ...that is to say, `second item` is passed as a completely separate argument to `do_cmd` from the argument in which `for_each "first item` is passed.

Comment: ...one thing you can do in bash 5.0 to avoid that while not throwing away data about your array's formulation is to use `${array[*]@Q}`; but then you're _needing_ to use `eval` to get the original word boundaries back later, and... ugh.

Comment: (If you need compatibility with releases of bash too old to support namevars, then we get into a place where some `eval` _might_ be needed; but there's a lot that can be done to minimize the scope of what data goes through that eval call unescaped; just `eval`ing the whole string _including_ data is a place you don't ever want to be if that data is ever outside your control; and I have horror stories of data loss events where people _thought_ that filenames were in their control and then things went badly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why The Original Code Broke

When you put `${array[@]}` in a context that can only ever evaluate to a single string, it acts just like `${array[*]}`. This is what your "working" code was doing (and why it wouldn't *keep* looking like it was working if your array values had spaces in their values or were otherwise at all interesting).

When you put `${array[@]}` in a context that evaluates to multiple words (like a command), it generates breaks between words at every boundary between the individual array items.

Thus, your string starting with `for_each` was split up into several *different* arguments, rather than passing the entire array's contents at once; so the redirection was no longer present in `do_cmd`'s `$3` at all.

---

### How To Do This Well

Starting with some general points:

- Array contents are data. Data is not parsed as syntax (unless you use `eval`, and that opens a can of worms that *the whole purpose of using arrays in bash is to avoid*).
- Flattening your array into a string (`string=${array[@]}`) defeats all the benefits that might lead you to use an array in the first place; it behaves exactly like `string=${array[*]}`, destroying the original item boundaries.
- To *safely* inject data into an `eval`ed context, it needs to be escaped with bash 5.0's `${var@Q}`, or older versions' `printf %q`; there's a lot of care that needs to be taken to do that correctly, and it's much easier to analyze code for correctness/safety if one doesn't even try. (To expand a full array of items into a single string with eval-safe escaping for all in bash 5.0+, one uses `${var[*]@Q}`).

Don't do any of that; the primitives you're trying to build can be accomplished *without* `eval`, *without* squashing arrays to strings, *without* blurring the boundary between data and syntax. To provide a concrete example:

```
appending_output_to() {
  local appending_output_to__dest=$1; shift
  "$@" >>"$appending_output_to__dest"
}

for_each() {
  local -n for_each__source=$1; shift
  local for_each__elem
  for for_each__elem in "${for_each__source[@]}"; do
    "$@" "$for_each__elem"
  done
}

cmd=( redirecting_to "$log_file" func )
array=( item1 item2 item3 )
for_each array "${cmd[@]}"
```

(The long variable names are to prevent conflicting with names used by the functions being wrapped; even a `local` is not quite without side effects when a function called *from* the function declaring the local is trying to reuse the same name).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Сan you please have a look on the [simplified code](https://godbolt.org/z/9fsefE9r8)? How it can be rewritten to avoid all the pitfalls, etc.? Note that the `do_cmd_named` also measures elapsed time for each command. Extra: in `parallel_for_each` how to avoid sequential waiting of PIDs?

Comment: @pmor, one _can_ use `wait -n` to avoid sequential waiting, or have a SIGCHILD trap that does non-blocking `wait`s when called, but TBH I generally use `xargs -P` to run a given number of concurrent processes; that's what it's there for, after all.

Comment: As for rewriting your code -- that's the kind of thing people pay me to do (and I'm not currently available for side gigs). If there's a specific place you're not sure about, though, ask a question and I'll see if I can extend this answer to demonstrate.